Sending Calendar event with HTML body in Outlook
I'm creating a Mail Service where I want to send emails with an .ics file and at the same time a body in html and display both things at once (.ics I don't want as an attachment). The moment I send an email with a Calendar and in it a Cancel method. Everything will display normally. But if I do a REQUEST the calendar will display but the html body will not. I have to restart the whole outlook and then it shows up. Is there any way to solve this ? Thank you
This is my code for creating the Calendar event:
    private Calendar createCalendarEvent(MailRequestDTO mailRequestDTO) throws ParseException {
        Calendar calendar = new Calendar();
        PropertyList properties = calendar.getProperties();
        Version version = new Version();
        version.setValue("2.0");

        properties.add(version);
        properties.add(new ProdId("-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 15.0 MIMEDIR//EN"));
        properties.add(new XProperty("X-WR-CALNAME", "Flexioffice"));
        properties.add(new Method(mailRequestDTO.getMethod().getValue()));

        ParameterList tzParams = new ParameterList();
        tzParams.add(new TzId("UTC"));

        VEvent event = new VEvent();
        event.getProperties().add(new Uid(mailRequestDTO.getReservation().getId()));
        event.getProperties().add(new Sequence(mailRequestDTO.getMethod().ordinal()));

        DateTime from = convertToICal4jDateTime(getTime(mailRequestDTO.getReservation().getReservationFrom(), true, mailRequestDTO.getTimezoneOffset()));
        DateTime to = convertToICal4jDateTime(getTime(mailRequestDTO.getReservation().getReservationTo(), false, mailRequestDTO.getTimezoneOffset()));

        String attendeeEmail = getMails(mailRequestDTO.getRecipient()).get(0);// Replace with actual attendee email
        Attendee attendee = new Attendee(URI.create("mailto:" + attendeeEmail));
        attendee.getParameters().add(new CuType("INDIVIDUAL"));
        attendee.getParameters().add(new Rsvp(false));
        event.getProperties().add(attendee);


        DtStart dtStart = new DtStart(tzParams, from);
        DtEnd dtEnd = new DtEnd(tzParams, to);

        event.getProperties().add(dtStart);
        event.getProperties().add(dtEnd);


        event.getProperties().add(new Summary("Flexioffice reservation"));
        String roomNumber = mailRequestDTO.getReservation().getRoomHeader().getNumber();
        String buildingName = mailRequestDTO.getReservation().getRoomHeader().getBuilding().getName();
        event.getProperties().add(new Location(roomNumber + ", " + buildingName));

        // Add ORGANIZER property
        Organizer organizer = new Organizer(URI.create("mailto:" + FROMMAIL));
        organizer.getParameters().add(new CuType("INDIVIDUAL"));
        event.getProperties().add(organizer);


        // Set description with HTML content
        ParameterList pl = new ParameterList();
        pl.add(new net.fortuna.ical4j.model.parameter.Value("TEXT"));
        pl.add(new net.fortuna.ical4j.model.parameter.FmtType("text/html"));
        pl.add(new net.fortuna.ical4j.model.parameter.Encoding("utf-8"));

        // ADD X-ALT-DESC
        event.getProperties().add(new Description(pl, createDescription(mailRequestDTO)));
        event.getProperties().add(new XProperty("X-ALT-DESC", pl, createDescription(mailRequestDTO)));

        calendar.getComponents().add(event);

        saveCalendarIntoFile(calendar);

        return calendar;
    }

And here is how i sent it:
rivate void sendMailToUser(MailRequestDTO mailRequestDTO) {
        try {
            // Send the message
            Calendar c = createCalendarEvent(mailRequestDTO);
            Session session = getSession();
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(FROMMAIL);
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(getMails(mailRequestDTO.getRecipient()).get(0)));
            message.setSubject("Flexioffice reservation");

            message.setContent(convertCalendarToString(c), "text/calendar; charset=\"utf-8\"; method=REQUEST");

            // Send the email
            Transport.send(message);


        } catch (MessagingException | ParseException e) {
            log.error("Error sending mail", e);
        }
    }

And this is what i want to have in mail body:
Correct mail
And here what i got:
What i got
When I open the mail, the content flashes and disappears. Once I restart outlook, everything works as it should.

I started writing a guide to different ways HTML is managed by calendar clients here - https://www.semcal.org/rich-content/ - basically there is no consistent approach to HTML descriptions yet, apart from STYLED-DESCRIPTION which is not really supported by any of the major client. Your approach may be ok, but also possible that Outlook doesnt like HTML in the DESCRIPTION property..

It does not matter, what html i paste inside X-ALT-DESC, every time when the calendar event is request, the html is broken. When the calendar is cancel it is okay.
